# Sharing to Stories - javascript adaptation

Tags: javascript, android, api, uri, instagram

I'm trying to make this code work in Javascript.

It's a sharing function to Instagram stories that imports a few images and colours in the app.
You may have already seen it sharing a Spotify song.

```
Uri backgroundAssetUri = Uri.parse("your-image-asset-uri-goes-here");
String sourceApplication = "com.my.app";

// Instantiate implicit intent with ADD_TO_STORY action and background asset
Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");

intent.setDataAndType(backgroundAssetUri, MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

// Instantiate activity and verify it will resolve implicit intent
Activity activity = getActivity();
if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
  activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

It's from [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories#android-developers) Facebook for developers article.

I searched everywhere but I can't find anyone talking about this...

I'm pretty new to this advanced coding and I don't even know if this is actually possible.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: this code is in java. What do you need exactly?

Comment: I would need to make it work on a website... maybe adapting it to js? idk...

Comment: This code is in java and specifically for android. You can't use it even in a java web based app. As I know there is no way doing this on a web page